# How to write regular expression to get parts from connection string?

Tags: c#, regex

how to write regular expression to extract content of metadata, provider, provider connection string
from

```
 metadata=res://*/ent.csdl|res://*/ent.ssdl|res://*/ent.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog={0};Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

I mean, I want to get

**Metadata:**`res://*/ent.csdl|res://*/ent.ssdl|res://*/ent.msl`

**Provider:** `System.Data.SqlClient`

**provider connection string:** `Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog={0};Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

Comment: Any reason you can't use `string.Split`?

Comment: @Oded - I think the main reason *not* to use split, is that the natural choice would be to split on `;`, but that character is also used in the database connection string portion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without assuming any specific order of the ConnString:

```
var connString = @"metadata=res://*/ent.csdl|res://*/ent.ssdl|res://*/ent.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=""Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog={0};Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True""";
Regex metaRegex = new Regex(@"metadata=(?<metadata>[^;]+)");
Regex connRegex = new Regex(@"provider\sconnection\sstring=""(?<conn>[^""]+)");
Regex providerRegex = new Regex(@"provider=(?<provider>[^;]+)");
Console.WriteLine("MetaData: " + metaRegex.Match(connString).Groups["metadata"]);
Console.WriteLine("Connection String: " + connRegex.Match(connString).Groups["conn"]);
Console.WriteLine("Provider: " + providerRegex.Match(connString).Groups["provider"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex such as:

```
^(res:[^;]+);provider=([^;]+);provider\sconnection\sstring=\"(.+)\"$
```

Gives you 3 capture groups, providing the parts you need.

Live example: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=JRGSO74516

Answer (score 0):

You can use named capture groups to define patterns for each category, which is supported by .Net RegEx matching. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) for an explanation on named capture groups.